# Having trouble dealing with NA values in YEAR column

Tags: machine-learning, data-cleaning

I was trying to clean a housing dataset to build a model. I was stuck on a step where I had `NA` values in `GarageYrBlt` column. The house doesn't have a garage and thus the `GarageYrBlt` column has `NA` in it. How should I handle them?

Here's my dataset:

```
  Id GarageType GarageYrBlt
1  1     Attchd        2003
2  2     Attchd        1976
3  3     Attchd        2001
4  4     Detchd        1998
5  5     Attchd        2000
6  6     No Garage       NA
```

These are just sample rows. I have a big data set with lots of `NA` values.

Answer (score 0):

Year can be a valuable feature for both regression and classification problem.In this case you can try label encoding the year column so that all NA values will be given one code.Since this column has a connection with Garage type as you mentioned it is better not to eliminate those rows.

Hope this is useful.Thank you